# User defined join in Informatica with DB2

Tags: db2, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We are trying to replace source qualifier override with user defined joins and source filter.

for below user defined join in Informatica source qualifier:

```
{A INNER JOIN B ON a.dept_id= b.dept_id
b.load_date between 20170712174712000000 and 20170904152656000000
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON a.emp_id =  c.emp_id}
```

for this I'm getting SQL query as

```
FROM A,B,C WHERE {A INNER JOIN B ON A.dept_id = B.dept_id
AND b.load_date between 20170712174712000000 and 20170904152656000000
LEFT OUTER JOIN C
ON  C ON a.emp_id =  c.emp_id}
```

I have tried replacing INNER JOIN in override query with NORMAL JOIN, as I saw it somewhere that informatica translates normal to inner join. 
The source database is DB2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about informatica, but the resulting SQL syntax that you listed in the question is not valid for DB2. The biggest problem is that you have the `JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause rather than the `FROM` clause. Not real sure how to fix that in informatica though.  Appropriate DB2 syntax though would be something like this:

```
FROM a
  INNER JOIN b ON a.dept_id = b.dept_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON a.emp_id = c.emp_id
WHERE
  b.load_date BETWEEN 20170712174712000000 and 20170904152656000000
```

This assumes that b.load_date is not a timestamp field. If you are using a timestamp field, the format for the timestamps should be `'2017-07-12 17:47:12.000000'`

Answer (score 0):

The T-SQL should be used in FROM clause not in the WHERE clause. Hence use:

```
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON a.dept_id = b.dept_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON a.emp_id = c.emp_id
```